# Unix command line java Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, unix, javac

I have java and javac installed on a unix server at my school.

I have a java file called `Test.java` that looks like:

```
package Spill;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }
}
```

Test calls a class called Grid in a file called `Grid.java`
and Grid calls a class called Cell in a file called `Cell.java`

All three files are in a directory called `Assignment`

While in Assignment I use the command:

> javac Test.java Grid.java Cell.java

and three files appear called `Test.class` `Grid.class` and `Cell.class` appear.

I set all files in directory to have read, write and execute permissions.

Finally I use the command:

> java Spill.Test

and get the error

> Error: Could not find or load main class Spill.Test

I also tried

> java Test

and got the same error

> Error: Could not find or load main class Test

What am I missing?

Edit: Not an exact duplicate, since the linked article had all the possible reasons for the error message, but I have information in my question that tells us it could only be not creating a sub-directory to correspond with the package name.

Comment: does this run locally on your own machine? And did you import the other two classes?

Comment: I did import the other two classes, Lebron James, but I have not tried running them on my local machine. They compiled fine tho, since javac worked, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your three classes must be in folder named `Spill` relative to your current folder, and you need to add that to your `CLASSPATH` (either with `.` or in full). The package is part of the class name in Java and must mirror on the disk storage. Assuming you're currently in the `Spill` folder,

```
cd ..
java -cp . Spill.Test
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you. This is what I was missing. I've been spoiled by IDE's in the past, and I didn't realize I had to create corresponding directories for my packages.